# Why is a variable automatically modified even though I am not modifying it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, variables

I simplified my code to get the error I required.

```
one = ['x']
two = ['y']
final_data = []
for r in range(1, 3):
    print(final_data, r)
    if r == 2:
        one[0] = two[0]
        print(one)
    final_data.append(one)
    print(final_data)
print(final_data)
```

The final data in 2nd loop is not modified but the end result is coming `[['y'], ['y']]` even though
I expect it to come as `[['x'], ['y']]`

Comment: This is just basic behavior for mutable objects like `list`s. If you haven't already, you should take time to read through https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html . It will help you avoid confusing problems in the future. The important bit here is `"Assignment never copies data."` which you are expecting it to with `final_data.append(one)`.

Comment: @Axe319 That's not assignment, though it works the same. `one` is effectively "assigned" to an index of `final_data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `one[0] = two[0]` you change the value in list `one` and in the end when you print `final_data` you get `[['y'], ['y']]` because in list `one` you have `'y'`.

You need for each iteration to create a **copy** of `one`. To copy a list you can use `[:]`. Then after you do what you want with `one`, copy `old_one` to `one`.

```
...
old_one = one[:]
...
one = old_one[:]
```

Try this:

```
one = ['x']
two = ['y']
final_data = []
for r in range(1, 3):
    print(final_data, r)
    old_one = one[:]
    if r == 2:
        one[0] = two[0]
        print(one)
    final_data.append(one)
    one = old_one[:]
    print(final_data)
print(final_data)
```

Comment: Yes, but the ['x'] is already appended to final_data and the final_data is changed to [['x']] after 1st loop then in second loop the modified one which is ['y'] got appended to final_data so it should be [['x'], ['y']]

Comment: @SrinivasPiccalo you append `one` to list not `x` and when you change `one` then `final_list` is changing.

Comment: Ok. Kindly tell how to get desired result that is '`[['x'], ['y']]` in the above situation.

Comment: @SrinivasPiccalo I'm kind ;), edited answer

Comment: @SrinivasPiccalo welcome, always remember when you write `list1 = list2` both array have same address if you want prevent this you need use `list1 = list2[:]` or use `copy()`, for more detail if you like read this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
final_data.append( one )
```

does not add the *contents* of list `one` but a reference to the list called `one` to `final_data`.

In C / C++ terminology, a "pointer" (or "reference") to list `one` is added such that by the time `r==2`:

```
final_data = [ <reference to `one`>, <reference to `one`> ]
```

So by modifying `one[0]` to be `one[0] = two[0]`, the *contents* of `one` are changed and consequently `final_data` will see those changes too.

Possibly a simpler solution is to:

```
import copy

...
final_data.append( copy.deepcopy(one) )
```

`copy.deepcopy()` generates - as the name implies - a full copy of the object, such that now a reference to a new `list` will be added to `final_data` in stead of (yet another) reference to the list called `one`.